# Loop that finds a word in a string

Tags: javascript

So, i'm working on a 'for' loop that will identify my name, Andrew, and push it into an array, but there's something wrong with it

```
/*jshint multistr:true */

var text = ("Andrew is really awesome and Andrew should be working on the project, but there is honestly nothing for Andrew to do.");
var myName = ("Andrew");
var hits = [];
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i ++) {
    if (text[i] === "A") {
        for (var j = i; i + nyName.length; i ++) {
            hits.push(text[j]);
        }
    }
}
```

Also, the second loop is supposed to stop when it reaches the end of myName.

Comment: I think you mean (i-j) < myName.length in the condition of the second loop and j++ instead of i ++. But there's still some logic missing, you have to actually check if the rest of the name matches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using JSHINT, so just read the error messages and it'll tell you exactly what's wrong.

> **Errors:**
>
> - Line 7: `for (var j = i; i + nyName.length; i ++) {`
>
>   'nyName' is not defined.
> - Line 3: `var myName = ("Andrew");`
>
>   'myName' is defined but never used.

JSHINT isn't much good if you don't pay attention to what it's telling you.

---

Also, your inner loop looks odd.

```
for (var j = i; i + nyName.length; i ++) {
```

Seems like it'll cause an infinite loop. You're perhaps wanting `j` with a different condition.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled `myName` in your for loop syntax and typed `nyName` instead, so chances are the script dies as soon as it hits that line.

Answer (score 0):

A typo in the for loop that wants to refer to `myName` would appear to be a big problem:

```
for (var j = i; i + nyName.length; i ++)
                    ^
```

Answer (score 0):

The misspelled `myName` isn't the only part that fails. You for loop will never end the loop because `i + myName.length` will always evaluate to `true`. You also need to increase the value of `j` or it will always get the character at index `i`.

Here's the corrected loop.

```
for (var i = 0; i < text.length; i ++) {
    if (text[i] === "A") {
        for (var j = 0; j < myName.length; i++, j++) {
            hits.push(text[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that would work, because j is supposed to correspond with i. j will not always be < text.length, because i increases at each repeat of the loop, therefore changing the value of j each time and raising it by 1. It will stop when the length reaches text.length.

Comment: The given code works. `i` is the current character being examined. If the `"A"` is found it consumes characters for `myName.length`. Proof of concept http://jsfiddle.net/97HsD/